# How do you unlock new character classes?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Simple question really. How do you unlock new character classes in **[Risk of Rain](http://riskofraingame.com/)**?

I've looked in the Unlockables screen and it isn't terribly clear.

Comment: @JerryRox http://riskofraingame.com/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The classes in Risk of Rain and how to unlock them are as follows:

- Commando: *(Unlocked by default.)*
- Enforcer: *(Unlocked by killing the Magma Worm, Wandering Vagrant, and Colossus. **Can be unlocked on any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Bandit: *(Unlocked by finishing the 3rd stage. **Must be done on Rainstorm difficulty or higher**)*
- Huntress: *(Unlocked by finding 15 monster logs. **Must be done on Rainstorm difficulty or higher.** Higher difficulties increase the likelihood to find monster logs)*
- HAN-D: *(Unlocked by opening a crate in the final stage. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Engineer: *(Unlocked by repairing 40 drones total. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Miner: *(Unlocked by fighting a mini-boss in the Magma Barracks, found on a separate screen entered at the bottom right corner on some map layouts. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Sniper: *(Unlocked by beating the game. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Acrid: *(Unlocked by fighting a mini-boss in the Underwater Catacombs, found in a cage at the top right corner on some map layouts. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*
- Mercenary: *(Unlocked by beating the game 5 times. **Can be unlocked in any difficulty, including Drizzle**)*

You can find more info on the [Risk of Rain wiki](http://risk-of-rain.wikia.com/wiki/Classes).

Answer (score 5):

Below you find the difficulty levels at which the characters can be unlocked. These don't all have to be done in one play-through.

- **Enforcer** – Drizzle and up
- **Bandit** – Drizzle and up
- **Huntress** – Rain storm and up (monster logs have a rare chance of dropping from enemies)
- **Han-D** – Drizzle and up, see [this video for more information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD8sQ-tGq4g)
- **Engineer** – Drizzle and up
- **Miner** – Drizzle and up, Magma barracks has to be on the fourth level see [this video for more information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-K3R-_4e20E)
- **Acrid** – Drizzle and up, see [this video for more information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YzC0pmvUe-k)
- **Mercenary** – Drizzle and up
- **Loader** – Collect 30 or more Different items in Drizzle and up
- **Chef** – collect meat nuggets, bustling fungus, foreign fruit, sprouting egg, and bitter root in one play through drizzle and up.

hope this helped and provided more info. :3

Comment: It seems that the first word may be a character, followed by a difficulty level – but really I am only guessing. Also, the videos you tried to link didn't end up in the post. You should edit the answer to provide an explanation what information is presented, and visually separate the different pieces of information. Perhaps you could take some cues from the other answer in that regard.

Comment: Okay, I proposed some formatting changes, perhaps you could check if the information presented remains correct.

Comment: Actually it would be best, if the two answers would be combined into one.